# Any idea why the material design "home up" button might turn black after rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, material-design

I am adding a fragment in portrait, rotating to landscape, then rotating back to portrait.  After the second rotation, the `home up` button turns black.  Any idea what might be causing this?

- I am using theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.
- I am using `ActionBar` on this fragment, but `Toolbar` on a fragment that is added in landscape.
- If I add the fragment in landscape first, then switch to portrait, it is black.
- If I rotate a third time to landscape it turns white, then black again when back to portrait.
- I am using this same `Fragment` in another `Activity` and I don't see this behavior.

[image: Action bar after two rotations]

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: @AlexLockwood Using `4.4.4` on a `Nexus 4` and `Nexus 7`.

Comment: @AlexLockwood I have narrowed the problem down to a `Toolbar` in a different fragment that I inject when in landscape.  I am guessing that when the device is switched back to portrait the landscape fragment is still around and the Toolbar is somehow effecting the `home up`.  If I remove that Toolbar the issue does not occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem as you. I use the toolbar in an activity containing a navigation drawer that hosts a number of frgaments some of which have listviews. Selecting an item in the listview starts a new details activity where I am using the actionbar and not the toolbar. On rotation the home up arrow changes to a dark grey and on subsequent rotations stays that color and does not change back to white even though I am using the Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar for the details activity.

I resolved this issue by adding a toolbar to my details layout and applying a dark actionbar theme directly to the tool bar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/details_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

I do not reference the above toolbar in my activity or fragment and still use the actionbar as I did before. I do not set the toolbar as the actionbar either using `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);` it's just present in my layout and nothing more than that, but now when I rotate the device the home up arrow does not change color and stays white as expected. It's strange, but works.

Edit:
I should have mentioned that the placement of toolbar in my details activity is such that it is not actually visible. Specifying the visibility of the toolbar to invisible still works `android:visibility="invisible"`

Edit: I wondered why this worked and it seemed very strange to me so I completely removed the toolbar and added the theme to the view group at the root of my layout. That makes more sense now.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:id="@+id/details_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```